# Bundle a Node JS application with MongoDB, Redis and Nginx into a .exe

Tags: node.js, mongodb, nginx, redis, exe

I am currently working on a custom cloud-based file storage system. The backend is almost done and supposed to be deployed on a personal computer or cloud-based server. The front-end is in progress and will be a Flutter app.

The backend is served by Nginx which is on top of a Node JS application that uses MongoDB as database and redis for the cache (as well as local storage for the files themselves).

In the best of world I would like to bundle all the back-end stack into one executable (and maybe one setup executable to install the required stack and configure it).

My question is, can NodeJS alone handle this ? I have searched and found out that one can set a starting script within the Node application but would it be sufficient ? Or should I go for some bash or even Java code to wrap everything ?

I don't really know in chat direction to look so I am really open to any suggestion here, what would be the best way to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using docker and [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/)?

You can create a `DockerFile` which is used to build your application container and include your whole stack in a `docker-compose.yml` file.

Then with having docker and docker-compose installed, you can bring your whole stack up in any environment.

For more info you can check out docker documentation, [this article](https://aleemisiaka.com/blog/docker-node-nginx-redis-mongodb/) can also help you :)

Comment: Hey Ana Lava

Thanks for the advice, I will take a loot at it ! :)